# Am I able to work in Germany but live in an overseas area of France?

Tags: france, visa, schengen

There are a lot of areas which are basically 'France' but are not actually *in* the country. For example caribean islands etc. ([Overseas France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overseas_France))

In my job I am not physically bound to any specific location. I thought maybe the '[Schengen-Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Agreement)' also works for overseas areas and generally enables me to live in France but work in Germany. Is this the case? I plan to live and work there for ca. 6 month if that matters.

Edit: In my specific case I want to live in [Guadeloupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guadeloupe) and continiuing to work in [Baden-Württemberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg).

Edit2: I'm a German citizen (no additional nationalities).

Comment: Which territory specifically? EU member territories are notoriously full of legal quirks, with France probably being the worst culprit for that.

Comment: @DPenner1 I've added my specific case to the question :) Hope that helps.

Comment: IANAL, but as best I recall Schengen is (solely/primarily?) about border checks, rather than free movement of labour.

Comment: Additionally, relevant (I think?) to the question may be whether or not you yourself are an EU citizen?

Comment: Related (duplicate?) at Expats.SE:  [Which EU territories outside Europe does an EU citizen have right of residence in?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/140/which-eu-territories-outside-europe-does-an-eu-citizen-have-right-of-residence-i)

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, expats is probably a better site for this question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start off by quoting Wikipedia on [Guadeloupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guadeloupe):

> Guadeloupe, like the other overseas departments, is an integral part of France. As a constituent territory of the European Union and the Eurozone, the euro is its official currency and any European Union citizen is free to settle and work there indefinitely. As an overseas department, however, it is not part of the Schengen Area.

Basically, as a territory<sup>1</sup> situated [outside of Europe, Schengen does not apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#Territories_of_Schengen_states_outside_the_Area), but as a territory situated in the European Union, [free movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizens%E2%80%99_Rights_Directive) applies, allowing<sup>2</sup> the scenario you describe. For France, this [is the case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_state_territories_and_the_European_Union#French_overseas_departments) for the territories of Guadeloupe, Réunion, Martinique, French Guinea, Mayotte<sup>3</sup>, and Saint Martin<sup>4</sup>. Other French territories are not generally considered to be part of the European Union<sup>5</sup>.

This means that French immigration law generally applies to these territories<sup>6</sup>. For stays of 3 months or less, no formalities are required as guaranteed by Article 6(1) of the [Citizens' Rights Directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32004L0038), other than holding a valid identity card or passport. While stays longer than 3 months can be subject to formalities, it [doesn't appear to be the case for a 6 month stay in France](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2651) (French link). However, if asked, you are required to provide proof of your employment.

---

1. There are specific legal terms at the French and EU levels for different types of territories. To avoid confusion and complexity, I'm sticking with "territory."
2. Allows, not guarantees. Your employer might object because of [tax ramifications](https://www.fieldfisher.com/publications/2012/06/international-cross-border-tele-working-beware), timezone issues, etc.
3. [Labour situation currently unstable](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouvement_social_de_2018_%C3%A0_Mayotte) (French link).
4. Unlike the others, Saint Martin is not considered an integral part of France and so expect more than usual amounts of deviation from French/EU law.
5. However, France [has chosen to extend](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=3CA56EABA0961229AED230C4BAA53A8B.tplgfr31s_2?idArticle=LEGIARTI000028921609&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&dateTexte=20180719) this EU freedom to the non-EU territories of St. Pierre & Miquelon and Saint Barthélemy (French link).
6. No answer on French overseas territories is complete without a final disclaimer that there can be deviations from normal French/EU law, so consult a lawyer if you're concerned (or likely better in this case, a French immigration official). However, I did skim the [relevant law](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do;jsessionid=C6892E3ABF8DA646F2EB527461FA5BA8.tplgfr31s_2?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&dateTexte=20180719) wherever Guadeloupe was mentioned and it seemed like all deviations were related to asylum or not being in the Schengen area.